# hover to get in banner from right and left and then fade away

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want hover to get in from right and left and then fade away its not working for me i am working on that but its not fixing i don't know what i am missing in my coding i know its simple but sometimes simple is the hardest assignment i need a guidance according to my requirement i don't know why its going out of page i almost tried according to my potential

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Assignment one animation</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
             $(document).ready (function(){
                $(".dd").hover (function(){
                var div = $(".dd"); 

                div.fadeOut().animate({width: "toggle"}, 5000);

                });
            });

            $(document).ready (function(){
                $(".bb").hover (function(){
                var div = $(".bb");  
                div.fadeOut().animate({width: "toggle"},  5000);


                });
            }); 

        </script>
        <style>
            .dd{
                position:absolute;
                left:0;
                top:1%;
                opacity: 0.5;
                width: 50%;
                height: 91%;
                background: #ccc;


            }
             .bb{

                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                right:0;
                top: 1%;
                width: 49.5%;
                height: 91.2%;
                opacity: 0.5;
                background: #ccc;
                margin-right:20px;


            } 

            #i{
                width:100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow-x:hidden;">
        <img id="i" src="images/3.png">
        <div class="img3">

            <div class="dd">

            </div>
            <div class="bb">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest you to not put  in the , you should better charge it after the

You mean something like that ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#square').hover(
  function(){
    $( "#square" ).animate({
      right: "50%",
      opacity: 0
    }, 1500 );
  }, function(){
    $( "#square" ).animate({
      right: "0",
      opacity: 1
    }, 1500 );
  }
 );
});
```

```css
#square{
  position : absolute;
  right : 0;
  width : 50%;
  height : 100vh;
  background-color : #F00;
  opacity : 1;
}
#square:hover{
  cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square"></div>
```

You can do it with only CSS by the way

```css
#square{
  position : absolute;
  right : 0;
  width : 50%;
  height : 100vh;
  background-color : #F00;
  opacity : 1;
  transition : all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
#square:hover{
  cursor : pointer;
  right : 50%;
  opacity : 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: i want it to work from right and left when they collide between they fade away like when from the right hover collide with left hover they will collide between the banner  and then fade away